# Horseshoe lemma for Cartan-Eilenberg resolution

Tags: homological-algebra

Let 
$$0 \to A^\bullet \to B^\bullet \to C^\bullet \to 0$$
be a short exact sequence of bounded complexes of objects in an abelian category with enough injectives. Does there exist Cartan-Eilenberg resolutions $A^\bullet \hookrightarrow I^{\bullet,\bullet}$, $B^\bullet \hookrightarrow J^{\bullet,\bullet}$, and $C^\bullet \hookrightarrow K^{\bullet,\bullet}$ such that
$$0 \to I^{\bullet,\bullet}\to J^{\bullet,\bullet} \to K^{\bullet,\bullet} \to 0$$
is exact extending the above short exact sequence?

This is probably well-known and I would like to know in which references we can cite this result.

Comment: I'm a bit confused—don't you need boundedness assumptions on the complexes to have Cartan–Eilenberg resolutions at all? I guess you could ask if you have a similar property for Spaltenstein's K-injective resolutions, though.

Comment: Yes, you need boundedness. I'll edit my question.